# how to add icon into custom listview while receiving icon URL from web server

Tags: java, android, json

how to add icon into custom listview while receiving icon URL from web server. i want add icon not url in listview. i am new pls help me here is my code

here is my json file on server.

```
   {"status": 200,"status_message":"Success","response":
  [{"platform":0,"logo":"http:\/\/betfan.com\/images\/servicelogo\/258.png",
  "name":"Andy Bell Racing","oppid":"258","hadtip":0},
  {"platform":0,"logo":"http:\/\/betfan.com\/images\/servicelogo\/327.png",
  "name":"Dog Race Wagers","oppid":"327","hadtip":0}]}
```

welcome.java

```
 package com.example.newapp;

 package com.example.newapp;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.net.URI;
 import java.net.URISyntaxException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Welcome extends Activity {

String[] temp_Arr;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<list>listitem;
String title;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    login();

    title="Free Tip - Betfans";

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvID);
    listitem=new ArrayList<list>();
}
private void login() {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Welcome .this, "Please while wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("device", "de3b5e2d7f401829ea54fd5aca9d2fa92deb65c1b9b6b7729b3c3c8df11e75f4");

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("userID", "2385");
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
                 try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("userkey", "d69b87b2c0ad828bf7c0c30b83ea0c11");
                } catch (JSONException e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("key", "MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0yM8VvP");
            } catch (JSONException e4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
          // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            String dataString = jsonObject.toString();

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", dataString));

            String result = null;

            try{


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet();

                URI apiurl = new URI("http://mobile.betfan.com/api/?action=v2list&device=de3b5e2d7f401829ea54fd5aca9d2fa92deb65c1b9b6b7729b3c3c8df11e75f4&key=MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0yM8VvP&userID=2385&userkey=d69b87b2c0ad828bf7c0c30b83ea0c11");

                httpRequest.setURI(apiurl);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            //Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Services received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            loadingDialog.dismiss();

                JSONObject respObject;
                try {
                    respObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    String active = respObject.getString("status_message");

                    //boolean status = respObject.getBoolean("status_message");

                    if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                         JSONArray array = respObject.getJSONArray("response");
                            for (int i =0; i<array.length();i++){

                         JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                         String logo= jsonObject.getString("logo");
                         String name= jsonObject.getString("name");
                         String hadtip = jsonObject.getString("hadtip");
                         String tipstr="";
                        if(hadtip.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                             tipstr = "Today's Tips ready.";
                        }else{
                             tipstr = "No Today's Tips";
                        }

                          listitem.add(new list((1),name, tipstr));
            //1 is any dummy integer because when i pass logo it gives error and application get crashed.
                        }
                         lv.setAdapter(new Custom_adapter(Welcome.this, listitem)); 

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "services received Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getname();

                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                    }
                });

        }

    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

here is Activitywelcome.xml code

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/lvID"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

list.java

```
package com.example.newapp;

public class list {
private int icon;
private String name;
private String tips;


public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
public String getname() {
    return name;
}
public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getTips() {
    return tips;
}
public void setTips(String tips) {
    this.tips = tips;
}
public list(int icon, String name, String tips) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.name = name;
    this.tips = tips;
 }



}
```

custom_adapter.java

```
  package com.example.newapp;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Custom_adapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
ArrayList<list>mylist;
public Custom_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<list> mylist) {
super();
this.context = context;
this.mylist = mylist;
 }

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return mylist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int  position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_adapter,null);
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconID);
    TextView title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titleID);
    TextView tips=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_tipsID);


    list list=mylist.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context).load(list.getIcon()).into(icon);
    title.setText(list.getname());
    tips.setText(list.getTips());

  }
  return convertView;
 }
}
```

Acitvity_custom_adapter.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/iconID"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_titleID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_tipsID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

please any one help me, all code working fine except icon , icon not adding in listview while i am receiving icon URL but i dont know how to add icon behind this URL. thanks to all tell me what i do and write me some code thanks.

Comment: use Picasso Library or any other image loader library.
https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, but how are you trying to make this icon look in your listview?

Comment: pls provide me some code if u can thanks @Shubham

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(mList.getIcon()).into(yourImageView);
 this is simple and easy to use

Comment: where i  can write this code which class?

Comment: @saim you are already using `Picasso` and exactly the place where it should be used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some mistake in your code at this line :

`listitem.add(new list((1),name, tipstr));`

what is "(1)"  here instead you should pass `logo` that you parse from the json response, like

`listitem.add(new list(logo,name, tipstr));`

If this doesn't help check if `list.getIcon()` is containing the `logo` url or not,

**Edit**,

you should update your `Model` class to accept `String` and not `int` as the `Url` of `logo` will be `String`

So do the following changes in your model class

```
String icon;
public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public list(String icon, String name, String tips) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.name = name;
    this.tips = tips;
}
```

This should clear out things,

Comment: 1 is dummy any integer because when i pass logo it gives error and application get crashed @Satyen Udeshi

Comment: you should change your model class, here you need `String` instead of `int`

Comment: can you `Log.d("Url",list.getIcon())` and see if it prints the url, inside your `getView()` method in adapter

Comment: where i can write this?

Comment: Inside your `Custom_adapter ` `getView()` method before your write the `Picasso` line

Comment: thanks i got the solution from your code, you have save my life thanks :)@Satyen Udeshi

Comment: Great just mark the answer corect to clear the unanswered questions queue,

Answer (score 0):

Simply go with this [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) and parse your image and text both using Volley. (Y)

Comment: i want open different activities according to list item,when click on it, how i do it? please anyone help me code is given in question.

Comment: i want open different activities according to list item,when click on it, how i do it? i want receive data from server according list item name, every item data is different! please anyone help me code is given in question.

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/  in this you can find the proper code for SingleItemView for every row of listview.

Comment: please anyone help me that i want toast clicked item name in new open activity thanks,

Comment: please anyone help me that i want toast clicked item name in new open activity thanks,